# Determine if in DST or not — IsInDaylightSavings()

Tags: nodatime

Is there a way to determine if a `ZonedDateTime` (in the past) is in DST or not?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we've actually made this nice and easy - you just need to call [`ZonedDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/NodaTime.ZonedDateTime.html#NodaTime_ZonedDateTime_IsDaylightSavingTime). This is implemented by:

- Obtaining the `ZoneInterval` from the time zone at the instant represented by the `ZonedDateTime`
- Obtaining the `Savings` part of that `ZoneInterval`
- Comparing that with `Offset.Zero`